# Sort JavaScript Array in Artificial Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array returned by a `REST` query that represents the number of items in a multi-step production process.

```
var steps = [
  { name:'Package', value:3},
  { name:'Assemble', value:1 },
  { name:'Ship', value:7},
  { name:'Preprocess', value:9 },
  { name:'Paint', value:5 }
];
```

I'd like to sort them in the order of the process, like this:

1. Preprocess
2. Paint
3. Assemble
4. Package
5. Ship

I have other alphanumeric sorts that I am doing with Underscore but I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Attach a sort order field to the objects and sort on that. Or keep a sorting order array separately or something. You can't do it without information on *how* these are to be sorted.

Comment: Do you want to order these by `value`?

Comment: @Matthi Preprocess has a value of `9` but it's first, so no.

Comment: @vlaz, I'd like them sorted as I show in my question by steps 1-5.

Comment: @vlaz True, that's the point. Was not sure where the order value would come from except from another array. But it is fortunately solved 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for the wanted order with numerical values for the position. Then sort by this values.

```js
var steps = [{ name: 'Package', value: 3 }, { name: 'Assemble', value: 1 }, { name: 'Ship', value: 7 }, { name: 'Preprocess', value: 9 }, { name: 'Paint', value: 5 }],
    order = { Preprocess: 1, Paint: 2, Assemble: 3, Package: 4, Ship: 5 };
    
steps.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => order[a] - order[b]);

console.log(steps);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object which mentions the priority on each name while ordering.

```js
let priority = {
  Preprocess: 1,
  Paint: 2,
  Assemble: 3,
  Package: 4,
  Ship: 5,
}

var steps = [
  { name:'Package', value:3},
  { name:'Assemble', value:1 },
  { name:'Ship', value:7},
  { name:'Preprocess', value:9 },
  { name:'Paint', value:5 }
];

const result = steps.sort((a,b) => priority[a.name] - priority[b.name]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using a precedence map for every step type so that I can use it in the compare function.

```js
var steps = [
    { name: 'Package', value: 3 },
    { name: 'Assemble', value: 1 },
    { name: 'Ship', value: 7 },
    { name: 'Preprocess', value: 9 },
    { name: 'Paint', value: 5 }
];
var stepPrecedenceMap = new Map([["Preprocess", 1], ["Paint", 2], ["Assemble", 3], ["Package", 4], ["Ship", 5]])

console.log(
steps.sort((stepA, stepB) => {  
return stepPrecedenceMap.get(stepA.name) - stepPrecedenceMap.get(stepB.name)
}));
```